# I've been fixing a bug on this share sms feature, but when I share via google messenger app it doesn't pre-populate the body of text

Tags: javascript, android, sms, messaging

I've been working on a share SMS bug where when trying to pre-populate an SMS text, it pre-populates text for all messaging services besides google messenger app. Is this a recurring problem to anyone else?

```
if (ver == undefined){ //not iOS
        if (device.isAndroid){
            window.location.href = "sms:?body=" + aEncode(shareSMSMsg);
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = "sms:?body="+ encode(shareSMSMsg);
        }
}
```

For google messaging only, once this action is called when a user clicks the share SMS button, it is expected to take the user to google messenger, allow user to choose a contact, and pre-populate the text message with the desired text.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution for this problem. It's a different approach but it a better approach for a share feature.

```
          if(navigator.share != undefined){
            navigator.share({
              text: shareSMSMsg
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
          }
          else{
            window.location.href = "sms:?body="+ androidEncode(shareSMSMsg); 
          }
```